# How to handle large data query on mysql with better performances

Tags: mysql, sql, database, mysql-workbench

At the moment, I am trying to run a specific query via MySQL workbench from three different table in 2 different DB schema and I can't achieve it.

I currently have a `track` and `completed` table in a database schema and a `location` table database in a different server.

1. The `track` table collects the start and end of a todo.
2. The `completed` table save the results
3. The `location` database is used to get the location of creation and completion of the todo.

## track

```
+----+----------+---------------+---------------------+
| tid | user_id | function_name | track_time          |
+-----+---------+---------------+---------------------+
|  1  | des     | create        | 2015-02-29 1 pm |
|  2  | des     | complete      | 2015-02-29 2 pm |
|  3  | greg    | create        | 2015-02-29 3 pm |
|  4  | greg    | complete      | 2015-02-29 4 pm |
+-----+---------+---------------+---------------------+
```

## completed

```
+-----+------+---------------------+
| tid | uid  |  insert_time        |
+-----+------+---------------------+
|  1  | des  | 2015-02-29 1 pm |
|  2  | des  | 2015-02-29 2 pm |
|  3  | greg | 2015-02-29 3 pm |
|  4  | greg | 2015-02-29 4 pm |
+-----+------+---------------------+
```

## location

```
+----+----------+---------------+----------+
| tid | user_id | action        | location |
+-----+---------+---------------+----------+
|  1  | des     | create        | subways  |
|  2  | des     | complete      | home     |
|  3  | greg    | create        | home     |
|  4  | greg    | complete      | market   |
+-----+---------+---------------+----------+
```

I am able to get a join result from two table in the same db schema below:

## Query result

```
+-----+---------+---------------+-----------------+-----+------+---------------+
| tid | user_id | function_name | track_time      | tid | uid  | insert_time   |
+-----+---------+---------------+-----------------+-----+------+---------------+
|  2  | des     | complete      | 2015-02-29 1 pm | 2   | des  | 15-02-29 2 pm |
|  4  | greg    | complete      | 2015-02-29 3 pm | 4   | greg | 15-02-29 4 pm |
+-----+---------+---------------+-----------------+-----+------+---------------+


select * from 
svr1.tracking t, 
svr1.completed c 
where 
t.user_id = c.uid 
and t.tid = c.tid 
and t.function_name = 'create' 
and t.track_time > '2015-02-29 00:00:00' 
and t.track_time < '2015-02-29 23:59:59'
```

However, I also need the `location` info in my query BUT the location table for one single day has 150 million records and it took forever to run as my mac's 16gb ram runs out even they are indexed.

I required the output to have

```
user_id,
create tid, 
function_name, 
track_time, 
create location, 
complete tid, 
function_name,
track_time,
location
```

which will give me an output like below:

```
des, 1, create, 2015-02-29 1 pm, subways, 2,complete, 2015-02-29 2 pm, home
```

This is the combine track info and results 
[image]

the user info

[image]

in location the ID is hashed mac address of user device, i wanted to find out the track time and the location recorded time for each particular user.
[image]

I wonder whats the best script to write to achieve it as running with workbench doesnt work for me.

Thank you for reading and any comments are greatly appreciated!!

Comment: Do you have any indexes?

Comment: @Sane yes they are indexes

Comment: can you please post the **show create table xxx** from your tables to see if there really are the correct composite indexes.

Comment: (1) The tables design doesn't make any sense. (2) Please supply the query you are trying to run (that includes `location`)

Comment: @DuduMarkovitz i didnt managed to get the location result query don know how to do it. i can get the result with track and result...

Comment: Did you design the tables?

Comment: @DuduMarkovitz no sadly. i took over from another person.

Comment: Can we assume that location.id is in correlation with track.track_time?

Comment: @DuduMarkovitz thanks! i had update a few screenshots to let u have a clearer picture

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I eventually solved the issues through another question post:
[How to get latest results by date when selecting from two table?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40836972/how-to-get-latest-results-by-date-when-selecting-from-two-table)

By exporting the results to another server DB, i am able to get what i needed via the code below.

```
SELECT
r1.uid,r1.tid,r1.insert_time,l1.location,l1.time,timeDiff
FROM
(
select 
r.uid,
r.tid,
l.time,
l.location,
r.androidId,
r.insert_time,
min(abs(TIME_TO_SEC(TIMEDIFF(insert_time,l.time)))) as timeDiff
from
locationDB.track_result_submitted_mac r inner join
locationDB.location_archival_2015_09 l

on androidId = id
where

l.time > '2015-09-23 00:00:00' and l.time < '2015-09-30 23:59:59'  and
r.insert_time > '2015-09-23 00:00:00' and r.insert_time < '2015-09-30 23:59:59'

and abs(TIME_TO_SEC(TIMEDIFF(insert_time,l.time))) < 18000 
group by uid,tid

) as t,

indoorloc.track_result_submitted_mac r1 inner join
indoorloc.location_archival_2015_09 l1
on r1.androidId = l1.id

WHERE 
(abs(TIME_TO_SEC(TIMEDIFF(r1.insert_time,l1.time)))) = t.tim and
r1.uid = t.uid and
r1.tid = t.tid

group by uid, tid
```