# How to get latest results by date when selecting from two table?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables and I would like to join then with a query.

`result` save the actual entry of results

`user_tracking` tracks the acceptance and completion of work, users can cancel and accepts work again at a later time.

```
SELECT *
from
svr1.result r, 
svr1.user_tracking u 
where
r.uid = u.user_id and r.tid = u.post1
and u.function_name = '7' #7 == accept work
and r.insert_time > '2015-09-23 00:00:00' and r.insert_time < '2015-10-03 00:00:00' 
and u.track_time > '2015-09-23 00:00:00' and u.track_time < '2015-10-03 00:00:00'
```

my `result` table had 1785 records within the period I wanted to track
but the above query returns 1990 records. I would like to know how can i filter to get the latest date accepted by user only.

in `result` table: uid,INT, tid,INT, result,VARCHAR and insert_time,TIMESTAMP

in `user_tracking` table: user_id,INT, post1,VARCHAR function_name,VARCHAR, result,VARCHAR and track_time,TIMESTAMP

the user_tracking function sample records, in this query the track time will change and the rest will remain the same.

[image]

Comment: can you add sample data and expected result

Comment: What's when you say the latest date accepted by user does that mean that every other column is the same except the `track_time`?

Comment: @AER yea. I think your answer is the right solution. i will need to validate my records first

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `GROUP BY` command with a `MAX()` on the required date, this will select the latest date of all the options (assuming all the other columns are equal). Code as follows (need to declare all columns because of the `MAX` unfortunately):

```
SELECT r.uid,
    r.tid,
    r.result,
    r.insert_time,
    u.user_id,
    u.post1,
    u.function_name,
    u.result,
    MAX(track_time)        
FROM
svr1.result r, 
svr1.user_tracking u 
WHERE
r.uid = u.user_id AND r.tid = u.post1
AND u.function_name = '7' #7 == accept work
AND r.insert_time > '2015-09-23 00:00:00' AND r.insert_time < '2015-10-03 00:00:00' 
AND u.track_time > '2015-09-23 00:00:00' AND u.track_time < '2015-10-03 00:00:00'
GROUP BY
    r.uid,
    r.tid
```

Comment: thanks @AER, seem like this is what i'm looking for!

Comment: @Desmond Just let me know if any nuances need to be changed for it to work for you and I'll update the answer

Comment: thanks thats what i need! however i think the group by r.uid and r.tid is enough